# Custom post type details page is not found and instead single.php page is returned

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type (

> my_product

) in WordPress and when i click on read more link to show post details but it returns to **single.php** page instead of **single_product.php** page template.
any help.
here is my code:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'my_product','posts_per_page'=>1,'orderby'=>'rand'));
            if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <a href="#" class="post-thumbnail">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        } else { ?>
                        <img class="media-object new-pro-slide-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/default.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"> 
                            <?php }?>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body media-body-white media-body-white">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><?php the_title();?></h4>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><b>بیشتر بدانید</b> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;
```

Comment: I have set the permalink to post name in settings > permalinks

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong file, you have to use single-my_product.php this is single-post_type, here your post type is my_product so use single-my_product.php instead single-product.php.